# Remove duplicates in one list box in another JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 list boxes. The leftBox has all available options the rightBox has that customers selected options. I know how to remove and add items from each listbox with jquery. What I am wanting to to is if the item is already in rightBox remove it from the leftBox. So on the onclick event I want the script to run.

This is my view.

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("SaveMarkets", "Partner")">                                               


   <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        @Html.Hidden("partnerID", Model.PartnerInfo.partnerID)
        @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Markets, Model.MarketNames, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", id = "leftBoxN", onclick = "populatePartnerName()" }) 
        @Html.Hidden("marketName", "",  new { @class = "pName" })
       <button id="grantAccess" onclick="return ajaxSubmitNotificationForm(this)">Grant Access</button>

    </div>
</form>
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("RemoveMarkets", "Partner")" id="removeAccess">
    @Html.Hidden("partnerID", Model.PartnerInfo.partnerID)
    @Html.Hidden("partnerMarketID", "", new { @class = "marketID" })
    <button id="removeAccess" onclick="return ajaxSubmitRemoveNotification(this)">Remove Access</button>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        @Html.ListBox("partnerMarketID", new SelectList(Model.PartnerMarketsList, "partnerMarketID", "marketName"), new { @class = "form-control  input-sm", id = "rightBoxN", onclick = "getSelectedValue()" })
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my JS:

```
function loadRemoveDups() {
    var found = [];

    $("#rightBoxN option").each(function () {
        if ($.inArray("#rightBoxN option".text, found) != -1) 
            $("#leftBoxN option").remove(found);
    });
}
```

My JS does nothing. Not sure how to do this.
Thanks

Rendered Html

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalMarkets" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="MyModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4>Manage Partner Markets</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div role="form"> 
                                            <form method="post" action="/Partner/SaveMarkets">                                               
                                                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                                    <input id="partnerID" name="partnerID" type="hidden" value="5" />
                                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="leftBoxN" multiple="multiple" name="Markets" onclick="populatePartnerName()"><option value="Central Indiana">Central Indiana</option>
<option value="Charlotte">Charlotte</option>
<option value="Columbus OH">Columbus OH</option>
<option value="Raleigh-Durham">Raleigh-Durham</option>
</select> 
                                                    <input class="pName" id="marketName" name="marketName" type="hidden" value="" />
                                                   <button id="grantAccess" onclick="return ajaxSubmitNotificationForm(this)">Grant Access</button>

                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                            <form method="post" action="/Partner/RemoveMarkets" id="removeAccess">
                                                <input id="partnerID" name="partnerID" type="hidden" value="5" />
                                                <input class="marketID" id="partnerMarketID" name="partnerMarketID" type="hidden" value="" />
                                                <button id="removeAccess" onclick="return ajaxSubmitRemoveNotification(this)">Remove Access</button>
                                                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                                    <select class="form-control  input-sm" id="rightBoxN" multiple="multiple" name="partnerMarketID" onclick="getSelectedValue()"><option value="1">Central Indiana</option>
<option value="2">Columbus OH</option>
</select>
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: for starters you need to learn to use browser console (F12) to check for errors. You have several and the clues provided in console will help you through some of the issues

Comment: I do use the console and it is not throwing any errors.

Comment: Can you put your code in document.ready function. Your click event is enclosed in loadRemoveDups which is not being called from anywhere in your code 
E.g
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#rightBoxN option").each(function () {
    if ($.inArray("#rightBoxN option".text, found) != -1) $("#leftBoxN option").remove(found);
    });


});

Comment: then there must be some code differences between real code used and what is in question. There are syntax errors  and invalid properties used in code above. They would throw errors in browser dev tools console

Comment: @user3509208 I am calling it from a button onclick event. I just forgot to show that in the view code I posted. Sorry about that.

Comment: can you add an alert in the loadRemoveDups() function and see if that shows up on the screen.  alert('I am here');

Comment: It is hitting the script. The alert is working

Comment: Then the code you have posted is not the same as what you are using in real page because `$.inArray("#rightBoxN option".text, found)` is invalid. it is trying to get the `text` property of a string

Comment: @charlietfl that is the code I am using.

Comment: What is in the found[]. By the looks of the function found array is null. I don't see any push where you are trying to add elements to the array. can you please confirm that as well

Comment: @charlietfl that doesn't raise an error it just returns `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following you can remove all the elements from `leftBoxN` select, that exist in `rightBoxN`.

```js
function loadRemoveDups() {
  var found = [];
  $("#rightBoxN option").each(function() {
    var op = this;
    $("#leftBoxN option").filter(function() {
      return this.text == op.text
    }).remove();
  });
}
loadRemoveDups();
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="leftBoxN" multiple="multiple" name="Markets">
  <option value="Central Indiana">Central Indiana</option>
  <option value="Charlotte">Charlotte</option>
  <option value="Columbus OH">Columbus OH</option>
  <option value="Raleigh-Durham">Raleigh-Durham</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control  input-sm" id="rightBoxN" multiple="multiple" name="partnerMarketID">
  <option value="1">Central Indiana</option>
  <option value="2">Columbus OH</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #leftBoxN option[text=Central Indiana]. That is the error I am getting

Comment: Not throwing any errors now but not doing anything either.

Comment: I know it is hitting the script because I added an alert. Just not doing anything else

Comment: I tried this. It removes all of the items in the leftBox  `var found = [];
    $("#rightBoxN option").each(function () {        
        if ($.inArray("#leftBoxN option".text, found) != -1) $("#leftBoxN option").remove();
        found.push("#rightBoxN option".text);
    });`

Comment: @HHPRy that is because of this line `$("#leftBoxN option").remove();`. Try to add the rendred HTML from the view source. Then probably we can fix it.

Comment: I'll have to add it above in my question. Too many characters.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Select all the options from the slect where no one is contained in the second one (i.e.: filter the option) and remove:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    var cacheEle = $('#rightBox');
    $('#leftBox option').filter(function(index, element) {
      return cacheEle.find('option[value="' + element.value + '"]').length == 1;
    }).remove();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<select id="leftBox">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select id="rightBox">
    <option value="volvo1">Volvo1</option>
    <option value="saab1">Saab1</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button id="btn">Remove Duplicated</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function loadRemoveDups() {       
    $("#rightBoxN option").each(function () {
        var currentEle = $(this).val();
        var domLeftEle = $('#leftBoxN option:contains("' + currentEle + '")');
        if ($(domLeftEle).length > 0) {
            $(domLeftEle).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks,
Prashant